# Keras - tensorboard callback hangs when monitoring embedding layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am trying to hook keras to tensorboard in order to visualize my embedding layer in the model. I am not sure why but after the epoch ends keras just sits there doing nothing, not writing log files or checkpoints. Code below (definition of model is irrelevant, it has a single embedding layer and a couple of GRU layers followed by Dense layer):

```
filepath="./logs/modelBasicGRU.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
#do the embedding vizualization
tb_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', histogram_freq=1, write_graph=False,
                          embeddings_freq=1, batch_size=32,
                          embeddings_layer_names=embeddings_layer_names)
#later you need to open cmd for environment and do tensorboard --logdir=\path\to\logs
#then go to localhost:port

callbacks_list = [checkpoint, tb_callback]


history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                              steps_per_epoch=10,
                              epochs=40,
                              validation_data=val_gen,
                              validation_steps=val_steps,callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

When epoch ends it just sits in this state:

```
Epoch 1/40
 9/10 [==========================>...] - ETA: 1s - loss: 6.8852e-04
```

I check my logs directory - it not writes checkpoint, it not writes any log files there. What is happening?

Notice - when I kill it after like 20 minute wait I get that:

```
 File "C:\Users\maxim\Anaconda3\envs\Py35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2235, in evaluate_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)

  File "C:\Users\maxim\Anaconda3\envs\Py35\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 712, in get
    time.sleep(self.wait_time)
```

I have a feeling that it indefinitely iterates over the generator (and my generator is ethernal, it never ends) instead of just taking a batch of of examples.

And just to highlight - I need visualization of embedding layer only, I don’t need anything else in Tensorboard. So if there is an easier way to visualize the embeddings - please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its a know issue with the callbacks: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3358

When exporting to TensorBoard it expects that the validation data is in memory and is not a generator. This is requred to build proper histograms and distributions of the data - so TensorBoard will need to see whole dataset at once. On the other hand, seems like even if you set histogram_freq=0 (no histogram logging) it still doesn't help for embedding layers, they seem to require whole validation dataset too.

As far as I see keras team tried to make embeddings have their own separate parameter embedding_data in order to ensure that you can visualize embeddings with differnt data than validation data but I don't see that it was implemented:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/7766

Hence, for now only solution is to push validation set in memory. First github link has a code snipped which wraps TensorBoard call back and before doing export to tensorboard it fills in the validation data variable effectively solving the issue - except the fact that you still need to push as much of a validation data as you want into memory.